# MySQL merged & weighted sorting on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

**EDIT**

Based on the feedback here, I have simplified my question and split the information to independent tables.

[sqlfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0c62)

Table **products**

```
id(int(11), name(varchar(80))
         1,       'Product A'
         2,       'Product B'
```

Table **features**

```
id(int(11), name(varchar(80)), weight(int(11))
         1,           'Price',              10
         2,             'Age',               6
```

Table **values**

```
id(int(11), productid(int(11), featureid(int(11), value(varchar(80))
         1,                 1,                  1,           '$0.99'
         2,                 1,                  2,             '10+'
         3,                 2,                  1,           '$2.49'
         4,                 2,                  2,             '10+'
```

**Question #1**

I have two products. I want to query my database to display all values for all products:

```
Get all unique values for all products
Result:
1. $0.99
2. 10+    (<- this is a duplicate, so I only want it once)
3. $2.49
```

How do I query this?

**Question #2**

I have two selected values. I want to query my database to display a sorted list of products based on the my values:

```
Get all products sorted by weight
My selected values are :
Value 1 = '$2.49'
Value 2 = '10+'

Result:
1. Product B (weight 16)
2. Product A (weight 6)
```

Product B should be the first result, since both selected values have a match ($2.49 and 10+). Those matches are linked to features.weight 10 and 6.

How do I query this?

**OLD, PLEASE IGNORE**

Here is the sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47a932/2

I having real trouble to get my query to work and unsure on how to solve this. Any pointers highly appreciated.

What I am trying to achieve is a weighted and sorted products list based on features I save in another table. This table holds feature-names as well as the individual product feature-values.

**The Use-Case:**

I have two select boxes on my site: One called "Price" on called "Age". These show

*Price*

- $0.99
- $1.19
- $2.49

*Age*

- 6+
- 10+

I have two MySQL tables: "feature" and "product"

**Table "feature"**

This table holds all my features and the feature contents

```
#########################################################################
# ID, catid, subcatid, productid, featureid, featurename, value, weight #
#  1,     1,     NULL,      NULL,         1,       price,  NULL,   NULL #
#  2,     1,     NULL,      NULL,         2,         age,  NULL,   NULL #
#  3,  NULL,        1,         1,         1,        NULL, $0.99,     10 #
#  4,  NULL,        2,         1,         2,        NULL,   10+,      6 #
#  5,  NULL,        1,         2,         1,        NULL, $2.49,     10 #
#  6,  NULL,        2,         2,         2,        NULL,    6+,      6 #
#  7,  NULL,        1,         3,         1,        NULL, $1.19,     10 #
#  8,  NULL,        2,         3,         2,        NULL,   10+,      6 #
```

**Table "product"**

This table holds all my products

```
############################
# ID, catid, name, image   #
#  1,     1,  ABC, ABC.png #
#  2,     1,  DEF, DEF.png #
#  3,     1,  GHI, GHI.png #
#  4,     1,  JKL, JKL.png #
```

The query I am using is:

```
$categoryid  = '1';
$selectage   = '10+';
$selectprice = '$1.19';

$query = '
SELECT * FROM feature
LEFT JOIN product ON feature.productid=product.id
WHERE (feature.productid IS NOT NULL AND product.catid='.$categoryid.')
AND (feature.value='.$selectage.' AND feature.value='.$selectprice.')
GROUP BY product.id
ORDER BY weight ASC';
```

Unfortunately this doesn't yield anything usable. What I like to output is the following:

```
#####################
# Results           #
# productid, weight #
#         3,     16 # matched 2x feature.value -> weight 10+6 = 16
#         1,      6 # matched 1x feature.value -> weight 6
#         2,      0 # matched 0x feature.value -> weight 0 = 6
```

Basically I would like to count all matched values and add their weights together to end up with a sorted list based on the sum of the weights.

Maybe I am missing something or did my DB structure all wrong.

Eternal sourcecode credit given to everybody helping out. (Will provide screenshots!)

Comment: what mean `weight 0 = 6` on `matched 0x feature.value -> weight 0 = 6`

Comment: A useful idea when using an EAV model, is to construct a separate table for each data type. That way, you can still take advantage of the benefits of indexes, types, etc.

Comment: ...but trying to combine an EAV and an adjacency list into one model sounds like a real headache

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to split which data in another table and how the query should look like? EAV... Will google that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0c62/5)**

**QUESTION 1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT `value`
FROM `values`;
```

**QUESTION 2:**

```
SELECT p.`name`, SUM(f.`weight`) as total_weight
FROM  `products` p 
JOIN `values` V
  ON P.`id` =  V.`productid`
JOIN `features` F
  ON F.`id` = V.`featureid`
WHERE 
   V.value IN ( '$2.49', '10+')
GROUP BY p.`name`
ORDER BY total_weight DESC;
```

Comment: This results in an error:
Warning: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:10+

Comment: I did a working sample for you and dont get any error. But with your data dont exist any row with `(feature.productid IS NOT NULL AND product.catid='1')`  check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f56f4/6

Comment: check my sqlfiddle -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47a932/2

i would like to get the results as in my above example. My current query doesn't work, so I need to replace that with something else that yields the results. never mind performance issues. :)

Comment: Did you saw my query? There is no way to get that result because source data doesnt match. Unless you want another join between `cat_id` and `subcat_id`

Comment: Whatever I need to do to make it work is fine by me. I am at this point clueless on how to approach the problem...

Comment: I will take another look later but you have to read.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers. And explain the relatioship between `cat_id` and `sub_cat_id`

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Will update with screenshot as promised when I integrate the code ... ;)